# string formatting with named index and a hashtable in PowerShell

Tags: string, powershell, format, string-formatting

I know how to use string formatting like this:

```
"{0,-20} | {1,5} | {2}" -f "bob", "3", "you@me.com"
```

But this gets very messy and confusing to read. Is there a way to use named indexes and a hashtable?

Something like this:

```
"{name,-20} | {age,5} | {mail}" ??? @{
    "name" = "bob";
    "age" = "3";
    "mail" = "you@me.com"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could approach it like this:

```
@{
    "name" = "bob";
    "age" = "3";
    "mail" = "you@me.com"
} | ForEach-Object { "{0,-20} | {1,5} | {2}" -f $_.name,$_.age,$_.mail}
```

---

If you're interested in simplification and readability, I'd recommend breaking it down:

```
$info = @{
        "name" = "bob";
        "age" = "3";
        "mail" = "you@me.com"
    }

$fString = "{0,-20} | {1,5} | {2}"

$fString -f $info.Name, $info.age, $info.mail
```

---

```
$info = [pscustomobject]@{
        "name" = "bob";
        "age" = "3";
        "mail" = "you@me.com"
    }

$info # prints with headers
$info | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders # prints without headers
```

Comment: This still seems messy. I was hoping there is some built-in way where you don't have to call each specific hash-table property. Something like a string templating system that other languages have.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan Why are you using hashtables/formatted strings and not other data objects?

Comment: Like what? I'm collecting data from AD and storing in an array of hashtables and then iterating through the array and printing it.

Comment: Like [**`pscustomobject`**](https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2016-10-28-powershell-everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-pscustomobject/). It sounds like you're over-engineering the solution; the data you collect from AD can be cast and printed without having to iterate, and without having to manually build an array (not sure if you're doing the second one). See edit for example.

Answer (score 0):

I try to avoid this kind of string formatting in PowerShell, since using variable expansion is usually much more readable. Even with your kinda rare formatting requirements, it still reads ok-ish. You can easily see which variable goes where, which is not the case when using the `-f` formatting.

```
$name = 'bob'
$age  = 3
$mail = 'you@me.com'

"$($name.PadRight(20)) | $($age.ToString().PadLeft(5)) | $mail"
```